# OpenGl with figures 3d

Tags: objective-c

I'm working with figures 3d, I need to know how to work with files .pod in xcode.
I'm using opengl, but not as work with these files.
From now thanks for any solution

Comment: check this out http://sree.cc/iphone/iphone-3d-objects-how-to-using-3d-max-xcode-cocos2d-and-collada2pod